# Part of the block disappears after applying CSS scale

Tags: javascript, css, zooming

I would like to zoom in div by clicking on it, but part of this block is hidden after zoom.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/xumuzine/2/edit

CSS property `transform-origin: 0 0;` is not suitable, because in the future I will need to track the location where I clicked and increase it to this place.

Thanks.

---

**UPD:**

Okay, guys.
I may not accurately explained the problem.

http://jsbin.com/fecaduxidele/2/edit

Here i add click event handler that receives the coordinates of the click, and makes zoom to click position.

And if I click to cell with number 9 (for example), I can't scroll my grid to cell with number 1.

Comment: 'part of this block is hidden after zoom'? what do u mean by this? you have a fixed width and height container, so u get scrolls there.

Comment: after zoom part of the image on the left and the top is not available

Comment: can u show on image how should it behave after click. I am not getting u exactly. If you use fixed width and height for both case before and after click, also keeping overflow: auto, it will add a scroll bar and the same behaviour which u see now.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/xumuzine/8/edit
remember that what is depicted in the upper left corner of the image. then press it. now you can not see what was on it.

Comment: so how u want it to zoom? zoom from center?

Comment: I want to by clicking on the picture, it was fully scrollable.
no matter from center it will zoom or not.

Comment: This is a VERY good question and I think the solution is going to be complex. I would use jQuery. You need to track with mousemove the position of the mouse and on click you need to store the position of the click. You need to 1) put the image inside a container with overflow hidden, 2) change height and width of the image (I wouldn't use CSS transform for that) and modify the margins of the image within that container (or use relative position) according to where the click occurred. A lot of work and I don't think it's a few lines of CSS code; but who knows?

Answer (score 3):

You could set the content size directly instead of scaling and use `background-size` to scale the image with it, e.g.:

```css
#content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(http://placeimg.com/300/300/any);
  background-size: 100%;
}

#content.scaled {
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  /* -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); */
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out; 
}
```

**Edit:** 
The above already fixes the issue of not being able to scroll to part of the image.  You can handle the coordinate issue with a JQuery animation (you can't control scroll position from CSS), but it will not be smooth because it does not synchronize with the CSS animation.  Your click handler would be something like:

```javascript
  var x = event.clientX,
      y = event.clientY,
      $this = $(this),
      scaling = !$this.hasClass('scaled');
  $this.toggleClass('scaled');
  if (scaling) {
    $this.parent().animate({
      scrollLeft: x,
      scrollTop: y
    }, 500);
  }
```

Here is the result applied to your second bin:

http://jsbin.com/jikididizice/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

The issue was if the parent and the child is of same size its will show a scroller as you can see in this fiddle

[**JS Bin**](http://jsbin.com/mesonozoluli/1/edit)

as you can see in the above fiddle i have added `scroll` and the `width` and `height` is same as the parent in `px` so the `scroller` is coming

the fix is you can give `100%` `width` and `height` like in the example i have shown below

if you dont want the scroller to come you can remove `overflow:auto` from the parent

[**JS Bin**](http://jsbin.com/budifeyabobe/1/edit)

you can also use `transform-origin property` to from where you want to scale the image like i have used `center center` in the example below so that it will scale from center

[**JS Bin**](http://jsbin.com/nuzubogarubu/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You should try with zoom property:

```css
#content.scaled {
  zoom:1.2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few solutions:

1. Remove the overflow auto of the wrapper.
   http://jsbin.com/xumuzine/40/
2. Scale the wrapper instead of the contents.
   http://jsbin.com/mojoyapamuyi/1/